# Populating a dropdown based on another in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get values to a dropdown list in my jsp page according to the selected value of the first dropdown list. I am calling a database query for getting the values to the second dropdown on select.change event by user. But I am getting empty value to the second dropdown list. I tried so many ways but didn't work any of them. What can be the reason? Anybody can help with this please?
Also I need to know that the second dropdown list should be coded as  `option = option + "<option value='" + data[sb].name + "'>" +data[sb].name + "</option>";` or as  `option = option + "<form:option value='" + data[sb].name + "'>" +data[sb].name + "</form:option>";` because I  need to record the selected value to the database as well. 
Thanks in advance

Code for the first dropdown:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showFirstList(Model model) {

        List<Map<String, Object>> firstList = countryRepository.getList();
        model.addAttribute("firstList",firstList);
        model.addAttribute("command", new Record());
        return "newFirst";
    }
```

ajax call for second dropdown populating.

```
$("#selectSecond").change(function(){
            var firstList = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://localhost:8081/countPro/getSecndList,
                //dataType: "JSON",
                data: {"countryNm" : countryNm},

                success: function(data){
                    var slctSecond = $("#slctSecond"), option= "";

                    for(var s =0; s<data.length; s++){
                        option = option + "<option value='" + data[s].name + "'>" +data[s].name + "</option>";
                    }
                    slctSecond.append(option);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error:function(e){
alert("error " + e);
                }
            });

        });
```

Controller method for handling ajax call :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getSecndList",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> getSecndList(@RequestParam("countryNm")String countryNm){

        return countryRepository.retrieveSublist(countryNm);
    }
```

Comment: Now where you are stucked?? whether second request is not fetching the result? whether option is not appending?? or first request itself failing??

Comment: As a courtesy to people who want to help you, please format your code and make it readable when asking questions.

Also this problem seems to be unrelated to Java and/or Spring MVC. From what I can see your `jQuery` code is buggy.

Try to reproduce your problem on one of JSBin, JSFiddle, or one of the many other online JavaScript playgrounds and it might be easier to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I guess a simple System.out.print() debug can help a lot here! first check if you really do call `/getSecndList` or not!

Comment: Here are some potential problems with your code: 1- You have `var firstList = $(this).val();` but you are not using `firstList` anywhere. 2- Your URL misses a closing quotation mark: `url: "https://localhost:8081/countPro/getSecndList`, 3- What's `#slctSecond`? What's `#selectSecond`? Are they supposed to be the same or are they different lists? 4- Do not create new elements by concating strings (read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) thoroughly).

Comment: @Sam I am getting the first dropdown list finely. But after selecting a value from the that list I put an alert to check the `data` of success function, it is showing nothing and second dropdownlist is not populating. I think the second request is failing or error-some ..

Comment: @Behrang
I have done some mistakes when copying and pasting it. `firstList` is for fetching the value of first dropdown's selected value as  `data: {"countryNm" : firstList}` and `slctSecond` is the second dropdown which is needed to be populated based on the selected value of first dropdown.

Comment: @SMash are you sure second request is reaching the controller?? can u put a breakpoint and check, if possible show the return list also

Comment: @SMash you can edit your question and copy and paste the correct code and format it too.